# How to launch Ubuntu Center from my application?

Tags: java

My Java application needs this library `libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni` to run successfully. So if the user doesn't have this library installed, I want Ubuntu Software Center to be launched and tell the user "you should have this library".

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is, but don't use Ubuntu center to do that. In pseudo code I would do something like:

```
 if result_of("dpkg --get-selections libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni") != "install"  
    then  
       ask user "Should the necessary libraries be installed?"
                "This requires administrator privileges"
       if yes
          gksudo apt-get install libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni -y  
       if no
          tell user "Necessary libraries are missing"
          exit
       end if
 end if
```

Comment: I agree! However, I would add "gksudo" to call the apt-get, and only after the user has been informed.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, the command to launch the software center is

```
/usr/bin/software-center
```

You can even specify a package name on the command line:

```
/usr/bin/software-center libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni
```

Comment: So would it be: `Process process = new ProcessBuilder("xterm", "-e", "/usr/bin/software-center").start();`? *(not tested)*

Comment: I think (without knowing Java!) that it would be `Process process = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/software-center", "libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni").start();`. No need to start an xterm, when you can start the software center directly. Can you try it for me?

Comment: actually, you're right ;)

Comment: @EvandroSilva Please consider the apt-get alternative presented by Frantique above.